# Why doesn't ps resolve usernames including dashes

Tags: ps, gnu

On Debian and Ubuntu (probably on other GNU systems too), when ps lists a process' user, it normally resolves its name, but when a process is running as a user which has a dash in its name, the user's numeric ID is shown instead. I think this is very annoying.

Is there a reason for this behavior or is this a bug and needs to be reported?

Comment: I can't say I've ever noticed this, are you talking about the UID column ?

Comment: @lain yes, for example in ps au or ps -ef

Comment: I don't see this.  For example: `www-data 20183 27367  0 Feb28 ?        00:02:45 nginx: worker process
www-data 20184 27367  0 Feb28 ?        00:02:58 nginx: worker process
www-data 20185 27367  0 Feb28 ?        00:02:50 nginx: worker process
www-data 20186 27367  0 Feb28 ?        00:02:48 nginx: worker process`

Comment: Do you have some weird alias or format option set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"ps" displays the UID number if the user name is too long for the display, On Debian systems which include the "Debian-exim" user it is common to see this as the UID instead. This is probably what you're seeing. The presence of a '-' is a red herring here, and it happens everywhere that uses procps, not just Debian and Ubuntu:

http://procps.sourceforge.net/faq.html

"Why do long usernames get printed as numbers?"

Comment: This had actually nothing to do with the dashes but with the length of the user names. Thanks for the information.